# Read and sum numbers from file

Tags: python

This is input text:

```
1 100
100 1
```

This is output text:

```
Please enter name of input file:  input.txt
Please enter name of output file:  output.txt
Sum from 1 to 100 is 5050
Sum from 1 to 100 is 5050...etc
```

My code:

```
def sum():
  file1 = input("Plese enter name of input file:")
  fileref = open("file1","r")
  file2 = input("Plese enter name of output file:")
  fileref2 = open("file2","w")
```

At the command prompt:

```
>>> print(sum())
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file1' for fileref = open("file1","r")
```

Comment: In the `open()` instruction, why do you quote your variable?  Try with this: `fileref = open(file1,"r")`.  Same goes for `file2`.

Answer (score 2):

```
def sum():
  file1 = input("Plese enter name of input file:")
  fileref = open("file1","r") #this is a  string not the input variable 
  file2 = input("Plese enter name of output file:")
  fileref2 = open("file2","w") # same here
```

You are passing the `string` not the `variables`file1`and`file2`

```
def sum(): 
      file1 = input("Plese enter name of input file:")
      fileref = open(file1,"r") # now the actual variable
      file2 = input("Plese enter name of output file:")
      fileref2 = open(file2,"w") # same here
```

You seem to have a few errors in your code, shadowing builtin  `sum` reassigning variables and trying to split on a `line` that does not exist etc.. also you never actually use `file_ref2`.

```
def my_sum(): # changed to my_sum to avoid major problems when using sum in your function
    file1 = input("Please enter name of input file:")
    file2 = input("Please enter name of output file:")

    # with close files automatically, you never use file2 but maybe you intend to write output to that 
    with open(file1,"r") as file_ref, open(file2,"w") as file_ref2: 
        result = []
         # x gets reassigned in your loop below, so this is redundant
        x = file_ref.readline()
        for x in file_ref:
            # changed to x.split(), line did not exist
            n, m = x.split() 
            # need to be ints for range
            min_number = int(min(n,m))
            max_number = int(max(n,m))
            for y in range(min_number, max_number):
                # not sure which x you actually expected here but the current x will give an error
                result.append(int(x)) 
                # in your code you were calling your own function here
                sum_result = sum(result)
            print('Sum from {} to {} is {}'.format(min_number, max_number, sum_result))
            # reset result for next line
            result = []
    # you were calling your own function again 
    return sum(result)
```

I used underscores for your variables and function name which is the recommended and pythonic way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need

```
file1 = input("Plese enter name of input file:")
fileref = open(file1,"r")
file2 = input("Plese enter name of output file:")
fileref2 = open(file2,"w")
```